# ActionBar setBackgroundDrawable() nulling background from Thread/Handler

Tags: android, handler, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to change the background of the ActionBar from a Handler.  The end goal is to pass the Handler to an AsyncTask, but for now even calling Handler.sendMessage() from a Thread results in strange behavior.  Through the debugger I'm able to see that the Handler receives the Message and subsequently runs setActionBarBackground() through to the end.

The default ActionBar with blue bottom stroke fully disappears from the screen and is not replaced by the new GradientDrawable.  I suspect that the background is being somehow nullified.  Furthermore, when I focus on the EditText again, the correct GradientDrawable ActionBar background appears.  The behavior I would expect is for the background to simple change on actionDone.

Any insight as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!

Relevant code:

TestActivity.java

```
public class TestActivity extends RoboSherlockFragmentActivity {

    @InjectView(R.id.ET_test) EditText testET;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(MainApp.TAG, "onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);

        testET.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    String loc = testET.getText().toString();
                    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
                            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(testET.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "EditText done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    /*TestQuery tq = new TestQuery(TestActivity.this, mHandler);
                    tq.execute();*/
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            mHandler.sendMessage(new Message());
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            //setActivityColors();
            setActionBarBackground();
        }
    };

    private void setActionBarBackground() {
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        //Drawable d = WidgetUtils.getActionBarDrawable(TestActivity.this, 0xFF00FFFF);

        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
                GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                new int[]{0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFF000000});
        gd.setCornerRadius(0f);
        ab.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
    }

}
```

test_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET_test"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:lines="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/ET_test"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@id/ET_test"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hendrik's workaround does the trick, but not when using a custom title view.  This works instead:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(newBackground);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

You may need a title set for this to work though.

Comment: thanks @Mat worked for me but if you need Title you can just alter the state of enabling title :)

Comment: If you don't know if the title is showing or not this works:    


boolean isDisplayingTitle = (actionBar.getDisplayOptions() & ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE) != 0;
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(!isDisplayingTitle);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(isDisplayingTitle);

Comment: I was facing a the same issue. I had added  bar.setBackgroundDrawable(newBackground); in the onCreate() method, but later moving the lines to the onPostCreate() it worked on orientation change.

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered the same problem. When I dynamically change the background of the action bar with `setBackgroundDrawable()` to a new `GradientDrawable`, the action bar turns all black.

I have discovered that this is connected to the action bar title. I don't use the title and have set it to an empty string. For testing purposes I set it to a test string "Test" instead and the problem with `setBackgroundDrawable()` immediately disappeared. Looks like a bug in ICS to me.

So instead of hiding and showing the action bar the following workaround works for me:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(newBackground);
actionBar.setTitle(".");
actionBar.setTitle("");
```

Comment: This workaround does not work for me :( ... only the hide/show works in may case

Answer (score 0):

Well this seems like a crazy edge case, and it happens with both ActionBarSherlock and the Android implementation of ActionBar.  I ended up calling ab.hide() and ab.show() to work around it...:(

Comment: This works.  One question.  Did you figure out how to prevent the rise and fall of the rest of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I am using ActionBarSherlock as well, and I too have wanted to change the background `Drawable` of the ActionBar via calls to `setBackgroundDrawable()` at arbitrary times. However, I found that after the background colour is set once, subsequent calls to `setBackgroundDrawable()` just don't seem to have any effect. I think that this is similar to the problem you encountered.

To get around it, I cheated. I just placed a `View` in my layout that would appear behind the ActionBar, and made the ActionBar itself transparent. The height of the `View` is easily set to the correct height by calling `getHeight()` on the ActionBar.