# android pager sliding tabstrip fragment changer

Tags: android, layout, switch-statement, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I want to change the layout by swyping over the tabs with fragments. Can anybody help me solve my problem?
Here is my fragmentactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private MyPagerAdapter adapter;

    private Drawable oldBackground = null;
    private int currentColor = 0xFF666666;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        final int pageMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics());
        pager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);

        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

        changeColor(currentColor);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_contact:
            QuickContactFragment dialog = new QuickContactFragment();
            dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "QuickContactFragment");
            return true;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void changeColor(int newColor) {

        tabs.setIndicatorColor(newColor);

        // change ActionBar color just if an ActionBar is available
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

            Drawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(newColor);
            Drawable bottomDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_bottom);
            LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] { colorDrawable, bottomDrawable });

            if (oldBackground == null) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                    ld.setCallback(drawableCallback);
                } else {
                    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(ld);
                }

            } else {

                TransitionDrawable td = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[] { oldBackground, ld });

                // workaround for broken ActionBarContainer drawable handling on
                // pre-API 17 builds
                // https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/a7cc06d82e45918c37429a59b14545c6a57db4e4
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                    td.setCallback(drawableCallback);
                } else {
                    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(td);
                }

                td.startTransition(200);

            }

            oldBackground = ld;

            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002691/actionbar-setbackgrounddrawable-nulling-background-from-thread-handler
            getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        }

        currentColor = newColor;

    }

    public void onColorClicked(View v) {

        int color = Color.parseColor(v.getTag().toString());
        changeColor(color);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("currentColor", currentColor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        currentColor = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentColor");
        changeColor(currentColor);
    }

    private Drawable.Callback drawableCallback = new Drawable.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable who) {
            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(who);
        }

        @Override
        public void scheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what, long when) {
            handler.postAtTime(what, when);
        }

        @Override
        public void unscheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(what);
        }
    };

    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final String[] TITLES = { "Categories", "Home", "Top Paid", "Top Free", "Top Grossing", "Top New Paid",
                "Top New Free", "Trending" };

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return TITLES[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return SuperAwesomeCardFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

    }
}
```

And here is my fragment that writes the numbers of the positions in a text view:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SuperAwesomeCardFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";

    private int position;

    public static SuperAwesomeCardFragment newInstance(int position) {
        SuperAwesomeCardFragment f = new SuperAwesomeCardFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        fl.setLayoutParams(params);

        final int margin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics());

        TextView v = new TextView(getActivity());
        params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
        v.setLayoutParams(params);
        v.setLayoutParams(params);
        v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_card);
        v.setText("CARD " + (position + 1));




        fl.addView(v);
        return fl;
    }
}
```

the library and the full code of the sample you can found here:

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: What issues are you seeing with your approach?  What doesn't work?

Comment: i want to change the layout view when i swyping and i dont want to print only a different text on every tab

Comment: Did you get an answer? I am having the same problem and it needs to be solved very urgently. Could you please tell if you have got the answer?

Answer (score 3):

I know its late but might help someone:

Here is the quick fix:

Create other layouts first, let's assume that you create 3: I am also assuming the layout to give a clear idea

```
layout/lay1.xml - has a textview only
layout/lay2.xml - has an imageview only
layout/lay3.xml - has both textview and imageview
```

now inside oncreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // if else or switch case, your wish
    View view;
    if (position == 0) {
        // means lay1.xml
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay1, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText("Content not available");
        return view;

    } else if (position == 1) {
        // means lay2.xml
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay2, container, false);

        ImageView imagebg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image1);

        imagebg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        return view;

    } else {
        // means lay3.xml
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay3, container, false);

        ImageView imagebg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        imagebg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText("this is working wow, thanks.");

        return view;

    }
}
```