# Using onclicklistener in a Fragmentactivity?

Tags: android

i have prepared an onclicklistener listview to put in a tab menu but after all done, i have noticed that such thing is not possible, i dont know may be with a small change to the code i can achieve what i need but my brain seriously stopped due to fraustrating:(   :

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private final Handler handler = new Handler();

private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
private ViewPager pager;
private MyPagerAdapter adapter;

private Drawable oldBackground = null;
private int currentColor = 0xFF666666;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    final int pageMargin = (int) 
 TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics());
    pager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);

    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    changeColor(currentColor);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.action_contact:
        QuickContactFragment dialog = new QuickContactFragment();
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "QuickContactFragment");
        return true;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void changeColor(int newColor) {

    tabs.setIndicatorColor(newColor);

    // change ActionBar color just if an ActionBar is available
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

        Drawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(newColor);
        Drawable bottomDrawable = 
 getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_bottom);
        LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] { 
 colorDrawable, bottomDrawable });

        if (oldBackground == null) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 
 Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                ld.setCallback(drawableCallback);
            } else {
                getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(ld);
            }

        } else {

            TransitionDrawable td = new TransitionDrawable(new 
 Drawable[] { oldBackground, ld });

            // workaround for broken ActionBarContainer drawable 
 handling on
            // pre-API 17 builds
            // https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base
 /commit/a7cc06d82e45918c37429a59b14545c6a57db4e4
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <  
 Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                td.setCallback(drawableCallback);
            } else {
                getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(td);
            }

            td.startTransition(200);

        }

        oldBackground = ld;

        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002691/actionbar- 
 setbackgrounddrawable-nulling-background-from-thread-handler
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    }

    currentColor = newColor;

}

public void onColorClicked(View v) {

    int color = Color.parseColor(v.getTag().toString());
    changeColor(color);

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("currentColor", currentColor);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    currentColor = savedInstanceState.getInt("currentColor");
    changeColor(currentColor);
}

private Drawable.Callback drawableCallback = new Drawable.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable who) {
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(who);
    }

    @Override
    public void scheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what, long when) {
        handler.postAtTime(what, when);
    }

    @Override
    public void unscheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(what);
    }
};

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final String[] TITLES = { "Categories", "Home", "Top Paid" };

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new TopRatedFragment();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new GamesFragment();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new MoviesFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

}

}
```

here my beloved listview :

```
 public class PinnedSectionListActivity extends ListActivity implements   
 OnClickListener {

 static class SimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> implements 
 PinnedSectionListAdapter {

    private static final int[] COLORS = new int[] {
        android.R.color.holo_green_light, android.R.color.holo_orange_dark,
        android.R.color.holo_blue_light, android.R.color.holo_red_light };

    public SimpleAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);

        final int sectionsNumber = 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
        prepareSections(sectionsNumber);

        int sectionPosition = 0, listPosition = 0;
        for (char i=0; i<sectionsNumber; i++) {
            Item section = new Item(Item.SECTION, String.valueOf((char)('A' + i)));
            section.sectionPosition = sectionPosition;
            section.listPosition = listPosition++;
            onSectionAdded(section, sectionPosition);
            add(section);

            final int itemsNumber = (int) Math.abs((Math.cos(2f*Math.PI/3f * 
 sectionsNumber / (i+1f)) * 25f));
            for (int j=0;j<itemsNumber;j++) {
                Item item = new Item(Item.ITEM, 
 section.text.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH) + " - " + j);
                item.sectionPosition = sectionPosition;
                item.listPosition = listPosition++;
                add(item);
            }

            sectionPosition++;
        }
    }

    protected void prepareSections(int sectionsNumber) { }
    protected void onSectionAdded(Item section, int sectionPosition) { }

    @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        view.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        view.setTag("" + position);
        Item item = getItem(position);
        if (item.type == Item.SECTION) {
            //view.setOnClickListener(PinnedSectionListActivity.this);

 view.setBackgroundColor(parent.getResources().getColor(COLORS[item.sectionPosition % 
 COLORS.length]));
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return getItem(position).type;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isItemViewTypePinned(int viewType) {
        return viewType == Item.SECTION;
    }

}

static class FastScrollAdapter extends SimpleAdapter implements SectionIndexer {

    private Item[] sections;

    public FastScrollAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override protected void prepareSections(int sectionsNumber) {
        sections = new Item[sectionsNumber];
    }

    @Override protected void onSectionAdded(Item section, int sectionPosition) {
        sections[sectionPosition] = section;
    }

    @Override public Item[] getSections() {
        return sections;
    }

    @Override public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        if (section >= sections.length) {
            section = sections.length - 1;
        }
        return sections[section].listPosition;
    }

    @Override public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        if (position >= getCount()) {
            position = getCount() - 1;
        }
        return getItem(position).sectionPosition;
    }

 }

static class Item {

    public static final int ITEM = 0;
    public static final int SECTION = 1;

    public final int type;
    public final String text;

    public int sectionPosition;
    public int listPosition;

    public Item(int type, String text) {
        this.type = type;
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return text;
    }

}

private boolean hasHeaderAndFooter;
private boolean isFastScroll;
private boolean addPadding;
private boolean isShadowVisible = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        isFastScroll = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isFastScroll");
        addPadding = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("addPadding");
        isShadowVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isShadowVisible");
        hasHeaderAndFooter = 
savedInstanceState.getBoolean("hasHeaderAndFooter");
    }
    initializeHeaderAndFooter();
    initializeAdapter();
    initializePadding();
}

 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("isFastScroll", isFastScroll);
    outState.putBoolean("addPadding", addPadding);
    outState.putBoolean("isShadowVisible", isShadowVisible);
    outState.putBoolean("hasHeaderAndFooter", hasHeaderAndFooter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Item item = (Item) getListView().getAdapter().getItem(position);
    if (item != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item " + position + ": " + item.text, 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    menu.getItem(0).setChecked(isFastScroll);
    menu.getItem(1).setChecked(addPadding);
    menu.getItem(2).setChecked(isShadowVisible);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_fastscroll:
            isFastScroll = !isFastScroll;
            item.setChecked(isFastScroll);
            initializeAdapter();
            break;
        case R.id.action_addpadding:
            addPadding = !addPadding;
            item.setChecked(addPadding);
            initializePadding();
            break;
        case R.id.action_showShadow:
            isShadowVisible = !isShadowVisible;
            item.setChecked(isShadowVisible);
            ((PinnedSectionListView)getListView()).setShadowVisible(isShadowVisible);
            break;
        case R.id.action_showHeaderAndFooter:
            hasHeaderAndFooter = !hasHeaderAndFooter;
            item.setChecked(hasHeaderAndFooter);
            initializeHeaderAndFooter();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private void initializePadding() {
    float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int padding = addPadding ? (int) (16 * density) : 0;
    getListView().setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
}

private void initializeHeaderAndFooter() {
    setListAdapter(null);
    if (hasHeaderAndFooter) {
        ListView list = getListView();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        TextView header1 = (TextView) 
 inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list, false);
        header1.setText("First header");
        list.addHeaderView(header1);

        TextView header2 = (TextView) 
 inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list, false);
        header2.setText("Second header");
        list.addHeaderView(header2);

        TextView footer = (TextView) 
inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list, false);
        footer.setText("Single footer");
        list.addFooterView(footer);
    }
    initializeAdapter();
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void initializeAdapter() {
    getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(isFastScroll);
    if (isFastScroll) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getListView().setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true);
        }
        setListAdapter(new FastScrollAdapter(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1));
    } else {
        setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
android.R.id.text1));
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Item: " + v.getTag() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

Comment: please explain clearly what is your aim and what is your problem.

Comment: well my aim is i need a sweeping tab screen with lists inside of it, i have a tab with list inside of it but i need the tabs to be also sweeping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think what you need is [navigation drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

or you can use [action bar](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html)

Comment: its not hero you deserved but you need.